# Retrieving the request object in a custom Django logging handler

Tags: python, django, logging, request

I have a custom Logging handler that I want to handle all logging message levels (INFO, WARN, DEBUG, ERROR, etc.) and send that to a data analytics server. For each message, the data will include fields on the record and on the original request object.

The problem is that I have not seen the request object attached to any of the records. I found on the official documentation that only django.request messages have the request object attached to the record, but no mention of what specifically django.request messages are. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/#django-request).

What are django.request messages? How/When are they fired?
How can I reroute every logging message to have the request object on it so that my handler can attach that data that will be sent to a proxy server?

----handler----

```
class LogHandler(logging.Handler):
    request = None

    def __init__(self, request=None):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)

    def parse_record_to_json(self, record):
        import json

        created = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created)
        return {
            'timestamp': created.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),
            'method': record.funcName,
            'level': record.levelname,
            'line': record.lineno,
            'module': record.module,
            'message': record.getMessage(),
            'path': record.pathname,
        }

    def emit(self, record):
        user_id = None
        try:
            self.request = record.request
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                user_id = self.request.user.id
        except:
            print "this must not be a django.request message"
            self.request = None

        from .event import SendEvent
        json_record = self.parse_record_to_json(record)
        level = json_record.pop('level', None)

        SendEvent(key="server_log",
                    name=level,
                    request=self.request,
                    obj=json_record,
                    user=user_id)
```

-----settings.py-----

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s  %(name)s  %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'splunk':{
            'class':'proj.common.handlers.LogHandler',

        }
    },
    # 'root': {
    #     'handlers': ['console', 'loghandler',],
    #     'level': 'INFO',
    #     'formatter':'standard',
    # },
    'loggers': {
        'django':{
            'handlers':['console'],
            'level':'INFO',
            'formatter':'standard',
        },
        'py.warnings':{
            'handlers': ['null',],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.request':{
            'handlers':['console','loghandler'],
            'propogate':False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: The sample code you present never uses your 'splunk' log handler. You have configured the `django.request` logger so that its handlers are 'console' and 'loghandler'.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the “what is a `django.request` message”: The `django.request` logger is one of the [Python loggers provided with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/logging/#django-s-logging-extensions). So, a `django.request` message is a log message sent to the `django.request` logger. As you've found, the [Django documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/logging/#django-request):

> Messages to this logger have the following extra context:
>
> - `status_code`: The HTTP response code associated with the request.
> - `request`: The request object that generated the logging message.

What may not be obvious is that “extra context” is provided with the logging message, and those items become attributes on the `LogRecord` instance.

So yes, in the `LogHandler.emit` method you defined, the `record` parameter is the `LogRecord`. The `record.request` attribute will be the HTTP request object, *if* the record was created on the `django.request` logger.

Your `LogHandler` will only receive messages if you direct them there, for example via the Django setting `LOGGING['loggers']['django.request']['handlers']`.